# What options exist to host a photography contest with advanced options?

Tags: web-apps, photography

I'm sorry I worded the questions so awkwardly but I'm looking for something incredibly specific. I'm looking for a platform where I can set up a photo competition where people can upload their photos into categories and voting takes place by showing visitors a certain number of photos and having them pick their favorite out of the bunch. I would also like for it to be dynamic in that it pulls photos from a database at random. This idea already exists in the form of [Shoot & Share's](https://www.shootandshare.com/photo-contest) yearly photo contest but I can't figure out if they themselves are using a specific platform or if it was developed in house.

I've seen lots of hosting contest hosting options like Survey Legend, Pollunit, Woobox, and Submittable. The closest one to what I wanted is Survey Legend but you have to manually set up the photos for the voters to vote on versus automatically pulling from an available pool of photos. Judgify.me was also pretty close but it doesn't look like it wants to show all photos at the same time versus 2-4 at a time.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not services – so this seems off-topic. For details, you might refer to our Meta post on [Are hosting recommendation requests on-topic?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/675/185) If you're looking for software to self-host, that of course fits here. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @Izzy That's a good question! I guess I never considered there would be a distinction. I'm fine with hosting the software but I'm also fine with using it online via a company's website. EDIT: I went through that meta post and I'm looking for is a Web App.

Comment: That makes your question fully legit here, thanks! May I suggest you **[edit]** it for a polish, so we can remove the comments – and all needed details can be easily seen? I'd specifically score the points of "self-hosting" and "web-app" – along the lines of "web-app (self-hosted if necessary)". For additional guidance, see e.g. [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185): the better you describe your needs, the better answers can meet them. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Disclosure: I work for PollUnit.

With PollUnit you can now create a "pairwise comparison" which presents to the user 2 random images side by side and the user has to choose her/his preference. This can be done in a configurable amount of rounds and we use a  [ELO rating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) to calculate a ranking.

It is also possible to allow users to upload their own images.

The pictures cannot be grouped into categories, but it could be possible to create a pairwise comparison for each category.

Here is our announcing [blog post](https://pollunit.com/en/posts/170/pairwise-comparison).

[image: illustrated pairwise comparions]